# How can I constantly check if a file is added in a folder?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a server that receives .txt files from the client throught cURL. It is then moved to a designated folder. Those .txt files have different names, according to client's ip address.

> ex. 192.168.5.n.txt (n=1 to 40)

How can I check files in that folder and return something to indicate that a new file has been added without reloading the page, also without being redundant? I am new to js, do I need Ajax for this?

Thank you.

Edit: I need to return something just in the web  page (ex. print $ipaddresstxt. "has been added";) not to the client itself.

Comment: You can use an automation software on your server maybe. Like the "Network Automation Automate" software.

Comment: This is just a simple server sir. That looks like a really big software :). I am kind of looking for a function similar to PHP's 'file_exist()'.

Comment: You need to sort this out on server first. Making requests from browser is the easy part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More like WebSockets, since the thing you want to detect is server side, and the server has no way to send an HTTP request to the client. You can create a WebSocket connection between the server and the client, and send messages both ways, whenever you need to.

Comment: I think I made a mistake in the question. I do not want to 'return something' on the client but just on the page like '192.168.5.n has been added'. I'll just trim the .txt extention.

Comment: Well that's still considered the client. My point is that if you want to send something to the user, and it's not a result of a direct request BY that user, then you'll need WebSockets.

Comment: Oh.. WebSockets sounds scary. I do need to return something to the client at some point. Thanks for that mention of WebSockets.